# Create new column on pandas DataFrame in which the entries are randomly selected entries from another column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with the following structure.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'tenant_id': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,7,7], 'user_id': ['ab1', 'avc1', 'bc2', 'iuyt', 'fvg', 'fbh', 'bcv', 'bcb', 'yth', 'ytn'],
               'text':['apple', 'ball', 'card', 'toy', 'sleep', 'happy', 'sad', 'be', 'u', 'pop']})
```

This gives the following output:

```
    df = df[['tenant_id', 'user_id', 'text']]

    tenant_id  user_id   text
      1        ab1      apple
      1        avc1      ball
      1        bc2      card
      2        iuyt      toy
      2        fvg      sleep
      2        fbh      happy
      3        bcv       sad
      3        bcb       be
      7        yth        u
      7        ytn       pop
```

I would like to groupby on tenant_id and create a new column which is a random selection of strings from the user_id column.

Thus, I would like my output to look like the following:

```
     tenant_id user_id   text         new_column
      1         ab1       apple         [ab1, bc2]
      1         avc1        ball          [ab1]
      1          bc2        card          [avc1]
      2         iuyt         toy          [fvg, fbh]
      2         fvg         sleep         [fbh]
      2         fbh         happy         [fvg]
      3         bcv          sad          [bcb]
      3         bcb           be          [bcv]
      7        yth            u           [pop]
      7        ytn            pop          [u]
```

Here, random id's from the user_id column have been selected, these id's can be repeated as "fvg" is repeated for tenant_id=2. I would like to have a threshold of not more than ten id's. This data is just a sample and has only 10 id's to start with,  so generally any number much less than the total number of user_id's. This case say 1 less than total user_id's that belong to a tenant.

i tried first figuring out how to select random subset of varying length with 
df.sample

```
    new_column = df.user_id.sample(n=np.random.randint(1, 10)))
```

I am kinda lost after this, assigning it to my df results in Nan's, probably because they are of variable lengths.  Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: `fvg` on `talent_id=2` is repeated. Is that expected? You have mentioned, sampling is done without replacement.

Comment: My bad, id's can be repeated for a tenant. The without replacement condition is wrong.

Comment: you 'new column' is not a new column, it's a new cell for a single row. if you want to assign the result to a new column, you need to create a new column, and `apply` the cell computation to it.
`df['new column'] = df['user_id'].apply(lambda x: df.user_id.sample(n=np.random.randint(1, 10))))`
it doesn't really matter what column you use for the apply since the variable is not used in the computation

Comment: Ahhh! Yes. MrE is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

per my comment:

Your 'new column' is not a new column, it's a new cell for a single row.

If you want to assign the result to a new column, you need to create a new column, and apply the cell computation to it.

```
df['new column'] = df['user_id'].apply(lambda x: df.user_id.sample(n=np.random.randint(1, 10))))
```

it doesn't really matter what column you use for the apply since the variable is not used in the computation